# jquery, how to get var from $.ajax POST?

Tags: php, jquery

edit3: i am using this script inside a facebook app, and not sure how to do it

i am passing a var to a php file using a post:

```
<div id="talentnum" class="cont_talentnum"><?php echo $number; ?></div>
<a class="mine_click" href="#"></a>
```

js here

```
 var strtalentnum;
$('.mine_click').live('click', function() {
    strtalentnum = $(this).closest("li").find(".cont_talentnum").text();
    $('#mine').trigger('click');

});

$("#mine").click(function(){
 if(strtalentnum){
  $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "fb_test.php",  
  data: strtalentnum,  
  success: function() { 
    var talentnum = strtalentnum; //this is 6203222
  alert(strtalentnum);
  }  
  });  
 }
});
```

and the php file is :

```
<?php
function fb_test()
{ echo 'xxx';
echo $_GET['strtalentnum'];
}
?>
```

then i call the function in the same html page:

```
<?php  function fb_test(); ?>
```

If i run this i get only the `xxx`. I also get the success alert `in my case '6203222'` so i know that the `POST` is happening

if i look in Chrome Network Headers i can see that :

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Form Data
6203222:
```

Why i cant get it using `$_GET['strtalentnum'];` ?

any ideas?

thanks

edit: `$_POST['strtalentnum'];` wont do the job either

edit2 added html

Comment: On ajax you pass POST not GET: `$_POST['strtalentnum']`

Comment: Or if your code requires a GET then change your AJAX method call `type` to `GET`

Comment: use .data instead http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable name for that:

```
var strtalentnum = $('#strtalentnum').val();
$("#mine").click(function(){
 if(strtalentnum){
  $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "fb_test.php",  
  data: "strtalentnum=" + strtalentnum,
  dataType: 'html',  
  success: function() { 
    var talentnum = strtalentnum; //this is 6203222
  alert(strtalentnum);
  }  
  });  
 }
});
```

Form:

```
<form method="post">
<input id="strtalentnum" type="text" name="strtalentnum" value="526558" />
<input id="mine" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Test it now:

```
<?php
function fb_test()
{ echo 'xxx';
echo $_POST['strtalentnum'];
}
?>
```

Comment: i see where this is going, i get something, i need to set it up so that when i click on he picture maybe i trigger the post button

Comment: yeah you can use `id` as reference `<img id="id_refrence_for_ajax" src="image.png" />`

Comment: You data needs to be an object {a:"b"}, not a string of "a=b"

Comment: even like `{a:"b"}`, still doesn't work, right now i am looking into `$("form").submit(function() {});`

Comment: still nothing, and the post approach is working just that i need it to do this: `$('#mine').trigger('click');` because now it refreshes the page and i get in a total different location

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST` and not `$_GET` to access variables passed via the `POST` method

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to get this by **$_POST['strtalentnum']** not $_GET['strtalentnum'].

Answer (score 0):

For you data you can't pass a string the variable needs a name you are essentially saying

```
fb_test.php?strtalentnum=
```

If it was a GET.

Change your data (in $.ajax) to this:

```
  $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "fb_test.php",  
  data: {strtalentnum: strtalentnum }  
  success: function() { 
    var talentnum = strtalentnum; //this is 6203222
    alert(strtalentnum);
   }  
  });
```

Comment: still doesn't work, i am doing `echo $_POST['strtalentnum'];` but with no result

Comment: in Chrome i can see that the Form data is `strtalentnum:6203085`, so i guess the data it's being posted, i just can't get it